# JLabel orientation causes error

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I am new to Java Swing. i cretaed a simple JFrame as shown below in the code, but when the line `statusLabel = new JLabel("statusLabel", JLabel.WEST);` is there i receive the below posted errors at run time, and when i comment that line out, the JFrame appears.

please let me know why this line `statusLabel = new JLabel("statusLabel", JLabel.WEST);` causes error.

```
public GUI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    prepareGUI();
}
private void prepareGUI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Swing Example");
    mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);

    headerLabel = new JLabel("headerLabel", JLabel.CENTER);
    statusLabel = new JLabel("statusLabel", JLabel.WEST);//this line when it is exist, causes errors

    mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
    mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI gui = new GUI();
}
```

**error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: horizontalAlignment
at javax.swing.JLabel.checkHorizontalKey(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLabel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLabel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at test.GUI.prepareGUI(GUI.java:23)
at test.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:15)
at test.GUI.main(GUI.java:31)
```

**Update**:

now after using .LEFT instead, the text that suppose to be placed at the .CENTER disappeared. why that is happening

Comment: `statusLabel = new JLabel("statusLabel", JLabel.LEFT);`

Comment: @MuratK. please see the update section above

Answer (score 2):

That's not a valid argument for the alignment.

From the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel-java.lang.String-int-):

> horizontalAlignment - One of the following constants defined in
>   SwingConstants: LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT, LEADING or TRAILING.

Edit- You're also adding both JLabels to the default position of the JFrame, which in your case will be BorderLayout.CENTER. That's why your JLabel is not visible. Either modify the layout of the JFrame, or place the JLabels in different positions in your default BorderLayout. More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

Comment: @user2121 This is the first result for googling "java JFrame layout": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: I hate Java Swing. I think it have a complex behavior and annoying requirements that force us to write thousands lines of code to achieve something simple. Now I'm fighting because I'm adding panels to a vertical scrolling panel but they insist on growing in height to take up all available space instead of having the fixed height stacked on top. Simple to solve with one line in CSS. Can't wait to finish this and get back to my web world. Those who don't know CSS and are doomed to this desktop world can criticize now.

Comment: ```JLabel.WEST``` : Compass-direction west (left). ```JLabel.LEFT``` : Box-orientation constant used to specify the left side of a box. Thanks for putting these 2 constants in same class. Zero score for intuitiveness. I will print the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `JLabel.WEST` according to the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> public JLabel(String text,
>         int horizontalAlignment)
>
> Creates a JLabel instance with the specified text and horizontal
>   alignment. The label is centered vertically in its display area.
>
> Parameters:
>       text - The text to be displayed by the label.
>       horizontalAlignment - One of the following constants defined in SwingConstants: LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT, LEADING or TRAILING.

The only options for horizontalAlignment are `LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT, LEADING or TRAILING`

So in your case use `JLabel.LEFT`

Comment: @user2121 try adding them in the opposite order statusLabel then headerLabel

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `JLabel`s in a `BorderLayout`

[See here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/WhatistheBorderLayout.htm)

Comment: can u please provide some example

Answer (score 0):

you could change this statement

```
statusLabel = new JLabel("statusLabel", JLabel.WEST);
```

to

```
statusLabel = new JLabel("statusLabel", SwingConstants.WEST);
```

notice to

```
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
```